# Increase MySQL max_connection on Lightsail (not RDS) database

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I have a database created in Lightsail (not RDS, just *Lightsail>Databases>Create database*). I am trying to increase its `max_connections` number from `150` to `500` by connecting to it remotely, but I am getting the following error:

```
Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER or SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN privilege(s) for this operation
```

Is there a way for me to achieve this on Lightsail?

**Database instance info:**

```
High availability MySQL database (8.0.11)
2 GB RAM
1 vCPU
80 GB SSD
```

Comment: It looks like you need to use the `root` account or whatever Admin account that you were given rather than a low level user account

Comment: @RiggsFolly How to though? All I have to connect is the username and password provided by Lightsail and associated with the db.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sound like you are attempting to set the parameter through SQL?

For lightsail databases, you need to follow these instructions and use AWS CLI: https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-updating-database-parameters

(if I'm wrong, please let us know what command you are running to generate the error you are seeing above)

Comment: I was just using `mysql -h <endpoint> -u <user> -p`. I am trying to follow the instruction on this guide, but I do not have a `get-relational-database-parameters` as a valid choice for `aws lightsail [option]`. I get a `aws: error: argument operation: Invalid choice, valid choices are:` followed by a list that doesn't contain this option (nor the update-relational one).

Comment: So your AWS CLI is setup and works correctly for other services in AWS? Have you got the latest version? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-install.html

Comment: I am using `sudo apt-get install awscli` and it gives me the version `1.14.44`. Is there any way to make sure it is the latest? EDIT: I used `pip3 install awscli --upgrade --user` and it did the trick :). I am trying to change the settings now.

Comment: `aws --version` --> will tell you the current version you have installed. Latest version is 1.16.247 according to https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/releases

Answer (score 0):

AWS RDS and lighsail wil automatically inject your proper amount of max_connections based on your memory installed.  With 2 gigs, you get around 66*2=132

It will just overwhelm even RDS if you make too many connections, as they require more RAM for each one.

```
"parameterName": "max_connections",
"parameterValue": "{DBInstanceClassMemory/12582880}"
```

mysql> show variables like "max_connections";

```
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| max_connections | 66    |
+-----------------+-------+

# pip3 install awscli --upgrade --user
# .local/bin/aws lightsail get-relational-database-parameters --relational-database-name <your given name>
# .local/bin/aws lightsail update-relational-database-parameters --relational-database-name <your given name> --parameters "parameterName=explicit_defaults_for_timestamp,parameterValue=0,applyMethod=pending-reboot"
```

which is required for MySQL 5.7

OR for your situation

```
# .local/bin/aws lightsail update-relational-database-parameters --relational-database-name <your given name> --parameters "parameterName=max_connections,parameterValue=500,applyMethod=pending-reboot"
```

If your region is us-west-2a, then remove the "a" from the .aws/config

```
[default]
region = us-west-2
output = json
```